# dynamicMemberLoookup ExpressibleByStringLiteral parameter swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a `@dynamicMemberLookup` model and I get an error which I do not understand. Any help as to how to solve this?

```
struct Blog {
    let title: String
    let url: URL
}

@dynamicMemberLookup
struct Blogger {
    let name: String
    let blog: Blog

    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Blog, T>) -> T {
        return blog[keyPath: keyPath]
    }
}
```

error

`@dynamicMemberLookup attribute requires 'Blogger' to have a 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' method with an 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral' parameter`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Your code compiles in my Xcode 11 beta 2 without problems.

Comment: Error is quite clear, you should have `subscript` with parameter of something that can be initialised with a `String` literal

Comment: I am using xcode 10.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're using `Swift 4.2`; KeyPath Member lookup has been implemented in `Swift 5.1`; Here's the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0252-keypath-dynamic-member-lookup.md)

At the moment you should use Xcode 11 which comes with `Swift 5.1`.