# How to access inner object's properties from superclass without boilerplate

Tags: swift, encapsulation, abstraction

Is there a way to create accessors of inner object properties without having boilerplate?

Here's an example of a class with the boilerplate

```
public class Foo {
    internal let bar: Bar

    internal init(bar: Bar) {
        self.bar = bar
    }

    private struct Bar: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }  

    // MARK: - Boilerplate 

    public var id: Int { 
        return self.bar.id
    }

    public var name: String { 
        return self.bar.name
    }
}

// Usage

do {
    let bar: Bar = try data.decoded() 
    let foo = Foo(bar: bar)

    print(foo.id)
    print(foo.name)
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to write the boilerplate? For larger objects with more properties this could be really helpful

Take Note: The Access Control Modifiers are important

Comment: How could you `let bar : Bar = try data.decoded()` outside `Foo`? Isn't `Bar` private within `Foo`?

Comment: Hello @RickyMo this is within the same codebase, outside the project this will not be possible. This question is made for encapsulation purposes and single responsibility

Comment: In Swift 5.1 you can do a "Dynamic member lookup,“ compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/56771120/1187415

Comment: Let me try that one.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I just realized that too, independently, and added a note about it to my answer. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

New in Swift 5.1, you can use dynamic member lookup with a key path. This works brilliantly for this sort of "has-a" situation, because key paths maintain full type checking. Here's a simplified example (with no attempt to mirror your actual situation):

```
struct Dog {
    let name : String
}
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct Kennel {
    let dog : Dog
    subscript(dynamicMember kp:KeyPath<Dog,String>) -> String {
        self.dog[keyPath:kp]
    }
}
```

The result is that, given a Kennel `k`, we can get `k.name` as a way of getting `k.dog.name`.

But saying `k.xxx` would be illegal, because a Dog has no String `xxx` property; that's what I mean when I say that full type checking is maintained.

---

The old way would be to use protocols. That way you can use protocol extension to inject the boilerplate.

```
protocol HasNameAndId {
    var id: Int {get}
    var name: String {get}
}

protocol WrapperOfHasNameAndId {
    associatedtype T : HasNameAndId
    var bar: T {get}
}

extension WrapperOfHasNameAndId { // boilerplate
    var id: Int {
        return self.bar.id
    }
    var name: String {
        return self.bar.name
    }
}

// ==============

struct Bar: HasNameAndId {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class Foo : WrapperOfHasNameAndId {
    let bar: Bar
    init(bar: Bar) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

// =======

let f = Foo(bar: Bar(id: 1, name: "howdy"))
print(f.id) // 1
print(f.name) // "howdy"
```

Comment: I guess this is the best solution, I'd have to write code but atleast the boilerplate is somewhere else. But it still doesn't work because I need `extension WrapperOfHasNameAndId` to be public and I the `protocol WrapperOfHasNameAndId` needs to be of **internal** scope. I guess there's no getting around this no?

Comment: Okay well in Swift 5.1 there's a whole new way to do exactly this. Ooooh, I see that Martin R has pointed this out in a comment. Added something about that to my answer. I think this is the directly you want to go in.

Comment: There was a good example in one of the WWDC2019 session talks, if I remember correctly. It was about implementing a COW value type, and forwarding properties to the internal reference type.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's session 415. However, this feature is valuable as a way of automatically forwarding to a wrapped object generally. Unfortunately there is no analog for automatic method call forwarding, though I don't see why they couldn't add that somehow eventually.

Comment: I see, unfortunately this feature I'm asking for is still unavailable.